# Trying to assign id to for loop function

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am trying to do is add an id to my dynamic info. This line

```
 var webaddress = '<img id= "[index]" src="http://pokeapi.co/media/img/[index].png">';
```

If I take out the `id="[index]` the loop works fine and gives me the images. But i need to add an id to all of them so i can do other stuff.  Bonus help would be nice if someone could tell me how to change the docuent.write(text) to write to a specfice div so i can put my script at top of page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" rel="script" type="script" href="script.jss"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {



    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    </div>
    <div id="pokedeck">
        <div id="pokelist">
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var webaddress = '<img id= "[index]" src="http://pokeapi.co/media/img/[index].png">';
            var text = "";
            for (var i = 1; i <= 152; i++) {
                text += webaddress.replace("[index]", i);
            }
            document.write(text);
            </script>
        </div>
        <div id="deck1"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: In what way is this code not working?  What is the current output?

Comment: Its not assigning the id with the id index part at the front the pictures dont render. If I take out the front index the picture renders just wont give me th e id.

Comment: what  is `152` there, you want to add 152 `img` tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Square brackets are special characters so you need to escape them.  See the code below (I have added comments to it)

```js
// the following goes in your document ready

var webaddress = '<img id= "[index]" src="http://pokeapi.co/media/img/[index].png">';
var pokelist = $('#pokelist');               // get your pokelist

for (var i = 1; i <= 152; i++) {
  var image = webaddress.replace(/\[index\]/g, i);  // escape your square brackets and make it a global replace - anything inside the / / is replaced and the g means all occurences of
  pokelist.append(image);                           // append it to your div
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
</div>
<div id="pokedeck">
  <div id="pokelist">
  </div>
  <div id="deck1"></div>
</div>
```

I would also move your scripts to just before the closing body tag rather than have them in the header